# How to safely rename a file/dir, changing case on a case insensitive filesystems

Tags: c, filesystems, posix

Recently I was using a file-manager on Linux, trying to rename a file which had the same characters with a different case.

The file manager reported that the file already exists (which makes sense on a case-insensitive file-system).

What's a portable way to check if a file can be renamed, without accidentally matching against its self?

---

Update, I couldn't find a file-manager on Linux that supports this (on vfat), so its possible this isn't something supported (without nasty hacks at least).

Even `mv nAme NaME` reports `mv: 'nAme' and 'NaME' are the same file`.

See [detailed discussion on the topic](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-08/msg00042.html).

Comment: Posix doesn't allow case-insensitive file systems, so the question cannot be answered portably. (See the rationale at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_06 for a discussion of why this decision was taken.) Would you be content with a Linux-only answer (although I'm not sure there is one of those either)?

Comment: Yes, but you asked for a portable solution, not a solution which is aware of the OS and filesystem in question. What I'm saying is that since the standard which defines portability (Posix) does not allow case-insensitive filesystems, it does not specify a portable mechanism for dealing with them. Mechanisms exist, but none is portable.

Comment: You could use `stat()` or `lstat()` on both names and compare the results.  If both names exist and the information from the two calls identifies the same file (the `.st_ino` and `.st_dev` are the same), then you're on a case-insensitive file system.  Then you'll need to rename the file to something distinctly different (that doesn't already exist), and then rename back to the name with the preferred case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That doesn't demonstrate that the filesystem is case-insensitive. It may be that the filesystem is case-sensitive but the two filenames are hard-links to the same entity. Also, there is a race condition between the two calls which could be particularly risky if the files are on a remote network filesystem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler... however, it was the heuristic I was going to cautiously suggest, combined with a prior attempt to `rename()`

Comment: Seems this a bigger can of worms then I expected, even core-utils can't do this: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-08/msg00068.html

Comment: I over-stated the case, though if the `st_nlink` is `1` in both cases (and `st_ino` and `st_dev` are the same), the determination is close to certain.  If the link count is larger, then there's no guarantee (`ln makefile Makefile` works on a case-sensitive system).  Yes, there are always race conditions on non-atomic operations, and two `rename()` calls are not atomic.

Comment: @johnathan: Yes, but note that after: `mkdir sub; ln -s sub SUB; touch sub/a;`, `stat` (and `lstat`) on `sub/a` and `SUB/a` will show both to have the same `st_ino` and `st_dev` with  `st_nlink` being `1`. (On a case-insensitive fs, you would leave out the `ln -s`, of course.) So you need to walk the pathname yourself with `lstat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with performing a temporary rename step, then by using the perl-rename utility, you can do a direct-inverse character mapping, where you shift one position the uppercase alphabet characters, and then you shift them back, but to lowercase instead:

```
prename 'y/A-Z/B-ZA/' -- *
prename 'y/B-ZA/a-z/' -- *
```

Note: For safety reasons, in case the glob expands to a filename beginning with a `-`, the end of optional arguments is explicitly declared with `--`, else some filename could be incorrectly considered as an optional argument.